# OpenVPN port-share with apache 443/10443 not working

Tags: ssl, openvpn, linux, apache-2.2, port

I configured openvpn (OpenVPN 2.1.0) and apache 2 ( to listen respectively on 443 and 10443 (with modssl). The two applications are listening well:

```
tcp        0      0 x.x.x.x:10443           0.0.0.0:*        LISTEN      1130/apache2
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*        LISTEN      7860/openvpn
```

But, for a reason I'm trying to determine, the port-share option configured as follow (with public ip) is not working:

```
port 443
port-share x.x.x.x 10443
```

The error in the openvpn log is:

```
TCP connection established with [AF_INET]y.y.y.y:3123  Socket Buffers: R=[131072->131072] S=[131072->131072]  
TCPv4_SERVER link     local: [undef]  
TCPv4_SERVER link remote: [AF_INET]y.y.y.y:3123
y.y.y.y:3123 Non-OpenVPN client protocol detected  
PORT SHARE PROXY: connect to port-share server failed
y.y.y.y:3123 SIGTERM[soft,port-share-redirect] received, client-instance exiting  
TCP/UDP: Closing socket
```

I suppose that openvpn has not the right to connect, but it is launched as root

> root      7862  0.0  0.0  99552   924 ?        S    Sep22   0:00 /usr/sbin/openvpn --writepid /var/run/openvpn.server.pid --daemon ovpn-server --cd /etc/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/server.conf --script-security 2

The 443 and 10443 ports are open on the firewall.

Thank you for any comments and suggestion !

I already consulted:

- [OpenVPN port-share with Apache/SSL](https://serverfault.com/questions/187915/openvpn-port-share-with-apache-ssl)

Edit for iptables rules:

```
Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:www
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:www
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:25
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:openvpn
ACCEPT     tcp  --  10.0.0.0/8           anywhere            tcp dpt:mysql
ACCEPT     udp  --  10.0.0.0/8           anywhere            udp dpt:mysql
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:10443
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:10443
```

Edit for better explanation of the error log:
The openvpn remote connection is working (I connect successfully to the VPN on port 443). The port forward is not working. HTTPS connection on 10443 is working, but HTTPS connection on port 443 is not working with port-share option.

Comment: Could you please show us the `iptables` rules?

Comment: Sure, I added input rules, feel free to ask for an other specific relevant section of iptables.

Comment: How about the iptables forward rules?  Also, do you have something like apparmor running?

Comment: My chain ufw-user-forward is empty. apparmor is not running.

Comment: Are you able to telnet x.x.x.x 10443?  Can you include pcap/tcpdump output of the interface that x.x.x.x is on when openvpn attempts to connect?  Does it just never get a SYN/ACK back?  If you ufw disable does it work?

Comment: Is your public IP directly assigned to a network interface on the server, right? You're not behind some sort of 1:1 NAT?

Comment: @polynomial telnet x.x.x.x 10443 is ok.

Comment: @polynomial disabling ufw doesn't change anything.

Comment: @polynomial the tcpdump output of x.x.x.x 10443 clearly indicates that openvpn does not attempts to connect. However, I get log when I connect myself throught https://x.x.x.x:10443

Comment: @Giovanni Bajo: checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer to this problem.

Despite firewall rules seems correct, the fact that openvpn were listening on a different host (public ip) than apache was the problem. Using same host (and public ip) for openvpn and apache solved it.